# Getting ZeroDivisionError when NOT dividing by zero

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app that returns a `ZeroDivisionError`. The numerator is zero but the denominator is not and the operation should return zero.

Using the Jinja2 debugger, I can query the variables to see that no division by zero is actually happening. See screenshot:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: BlackAnubis7 answer seems to solve your problem. But please, next time post your code as text using the code feature of the Stackoverlow editor. No developer likes to analyze code in a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remember about operator precedence. Your calculation seems to do `0 / 0 + 1529.657...`. Division `0 / 0` is being done first, and so your operation results in `ZeroDivisionError`

To solve your problem, put everything behind division sign in parentheses, to make it `0 / (0 + 1529.657...)`

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed missing a parenthesis!